# How to extract the singer's voice from a song using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

**I tried with this [command](https://superuser.com/questions/1408044/isolating-separating-vocals-from-audio-by-ffmpeg):**

`ffmpeg -i song.mp3 -af pan="stereo|c0=c0|c1=-1*c1" -ac 1 karaoke.mp3`

**But the output was the music without the singer's voice**

**:)** Is this possible with `FFMPEG`?
**Is there an alternative?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good alternative is "Demucs".

for more info see [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/demucs)